# Is this possible to have pagination, where we can jump pages, in django?

Tags: python, django, pagination

Let me clear my question further.

I have this code in my django 1.10 template which provides pagination.

```
{% block pagination %}
{% if is_paginated %}

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="page-links">
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
    <a href="{{ request.path }}?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
    {% endif %}
    <span class="page-current">
    Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
    </span>
    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
    <a href="{{ request.path }}?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
    {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>

{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Now the problem is by default you get pagination like `previous Page 1 of 119. next` but sometime we do not want to go one by one but want to jump the pages. Like I would like to go to page number 10. So rater than clicking next 10 times, wouldn't it be nice to have  1 to 10 written in pagination and we could click to any page and reach there rather than clicking next, next, next everytime.

Is this possible in django template?

Comment: I think [this](https://www.tummy.com/articles/django-pagination/) is exactly what you're looking for. I have used it and works perfectly! Also, it can be customised to fit your needs.

Comment: Nice, this is what I am looking for. Let me check and implement it. Thanks